# Spring @SessionAttribute and session.getAttribute clash

Tags: spring, session

I am experiencing a weird issue using spring mvc and session items.
We have a controller class annotated as follows:

```
@SessionAttributes({"customerPosition"})
```

according to the Spring doc, if I put into the model an object with the key `customerPosition` it gets automatically put into the session.

When I "manually" set the item with `session.setAttribute("customerPosition",customerPosition)` I exepect the item to be saved in session. if I get this item from the session by means of `session.getAttribute("customerPosition")` I get a different Item, not the one I expect. Actually what I get is data from previous iterations of the software flow.

It looks like that `session.setAttribute("customerPosition",customerPosition)` is not overwriting the object in session.

Does using `@SessionAttributes` prevents the possibility to manually control the session by means of `session.setAttribute("customerPosition", customerPosition)`

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps `session.setAttribute(...)` is being invoked outside a managed bean.  Can you post a minimal example to create the issue?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I cannot replicate the whole code, since it's long, but, I cannot exclude that somewhere session is being passed around. But Is it a good practice to manually set variables in session, when @SessionAttributes is used? Does it overwrite things that I set manually?

Comment: [This older article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/) might help.  Basically, it seems the Spring managed attributes are not copied to the underlying session until _after_ the controller method returns.  So any manual manipulation of the same session which has the same session attribute key will be overwritten when the method returns.  It seems the best approach is to be consistent - use either @SessionAtributes or manually, but not both.